# Nested foreach loop not functioning correctly. - wp

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post types 'stockist' and 'product', the latter having a taxonomy 'range'. Products are assigned to stockists using an ACF Post Object.

I'm trying to loop through 'stockist', return the 'range' term from the post object and then list the products for each term. So far I can loop all stockists and return all range terms however the foreach loop that returns the product list doesn't appear to be looping as it only returns the first set of values for each stockist.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php                           
$args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'stockist', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$stockistloop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): while ( $stockistloop2->have_posts() ): $stockistloop2->the_post();?>
<div class="col-1-1 clearfix nopad stockist-block-dropdown <?php the_title();?>-block">
    <?php 
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'range', 'hide_empty' => 0);
$categories = get_categories($args);
 if($categories): foreach($categories as $category): $url = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>
    <div class="col-1-5">
        <h4>
            <?php echo ($category->name) ;?>
        </h4>
        <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
            <?php $post_objects = get_field('stocked_range'); if( $post_objects ): 
            foreach( $post_objects as $post): $post_terms_array = get_the_terms($post, 'range'); $post_term_name = $post_terms_array[0]->slug; 
            setup_postdata($post); 
            if($post_term_name == $category->slug):?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endif;
            endforeach; 
            endif;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Replacing the inner loop with the following has resolved the issue:

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field('stocked_range');
if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <ul class="stockist-block-products clearfix">
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): $post_terms_array = get_the_terms($post_object, 'range'); $post_term_name = $post_terms_array[0]->slug; 
        if($post_term_name == $category->slug):?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a>
            <span>Post Object Custom Field: <?php the_field('field_name', $post_object->ID); ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Try to add `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `</li><?php endif;` in the second `foreach` block.

Comment: Sadly that hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Looking through the ACF documentation I've swapped the term name loop for the alternative which doesnt require setting up post data. This seems to . have resolved my issues.

Comment: Glad to hear that. And you should share the solution as an answer, because it could help save someone's time. =)

Comment: Just updated my original post to show the correct code. :)

Comment: I see. (And upvoted it for your efforts. ;)) Cheers!